# Помогите понять синтаксис

Tags: css

```
background: conic-gradient(#000 0.25turn, #fff 0.25turn 0.5turn, #000 0.5turn 0.75turn, #fff 0.75turn) top left / 50% 6%;
```

Я не понимаю что делает `top left / 50% 6%`. Что это за синтаксис?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Ответ

Тут стоит понимать, что [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background) это сокращение, для того чтобы сразу можно было установить несколько свойств. А именно `background-clip`, `background-color`, `background-image`, `background-origin`, `background-position`, `background-repeat`, `background-size`, и `background-attachment` **(порядок важен!)**.

> Я не понимаю что делает `top left / 50% 6%`.

`top` Это установка свойства `background-position-x` которое указывает начало отрисвоки фона относительно оси **X**, `right` это свойство `background-position-y` соотвественно работает аналогично, но по оси **Y**

`50% 6%` это css свойство `background-size`, отвечает за размер фона, первое значение это ширина, а второе высота

#### Пример

Пока готовил ответ, накидал вам простенький пример для понимания работы свойства `background-position`

```js
function changeBgPos(y, x) {
  document.body.style.backgroundPositionX = x;
  document.body.style.backgroundPositionY = y;
}
```

```css
html,
body,
.block {
  height: 100%;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

body {
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/pAG5V38.jpg") top left / 15% 25%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <input value="top left" onclick="changeBgPos('top','left')" type="button">
  <input value="top right" onclick="changeBgPos('top','right')" type="button">
  <input value="bottom left" onclick="changeBgPos('bottom','left')" type="button">
  <input value="bottom right" onclick="changeBgPos('bottom','right')" type="button">
</div>
```

#### Совет

Для работы с такими сокращающими свойствами советую использовать **Dev Tools** в вашем браузере, кликнув по такому свойству вы увидите все его содержимое в удобном формате!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]